# Sub tabs inside main tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently new to PHP and i'm trying to create a page where there are multiple tab panels.

What i'm trying to accomplish is how to put a new set of tabs inside the main tab.

Here's my page design script

```
<!-- BEGIN CONTAINER -->
<div class="page-container">
    <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="page-content">
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="portlet-body">
                        <div class="loading display-hide">
                            <img src="/assets/img/loader.gif" />
                        </div>
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="#workstation" data-url="cdr.php">Concentrix Cost in USD</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#workstation" data-url="monthly.php">Concentrix Usage in Minutes</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>

                                <a href="#workstation" data-url="pgi.php">I WANT TO PUT THE SUBTABS INSIDE THIS TAB</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class=" tab-content ">
                            <div class="tab-pane active " id="workstation ">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE CONTENT-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END CONTENT -->
</div>
<!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

Your inputs would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As in jQuery tabs? Try jQuery nested tabs: http://jsfiddle.net/bpJUv/1/

Comment: @justbaron I'm gon' try this out. :) THanks for this mate. I'll let you know!

Comment: where is the php here? This is plain HTML. Are you using any framework like jQuery? Do you plan to use javascript for that?

Comment: Removing the php tag and replacing with javascript/J query as these tabs are more suited.

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery nested tabs: http://jsfiddle.net/bpJUv/1/

Example:

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
$('#tabs1').tabs();
$('#tabs2').tabs();
```

or

For CSS drop-down menu, try something like this: https://css-tricks.com/targetting-menu-elements-submenus-navigation-bar/